Is a man allowed to defend himself from a woman?
Is a man allowed to defend himself from a woman in Islam? what if a woman is repeatedly punching or choking the men and the man is getting really injured. how do you defend yourself? and what if me as a boy is getting repeatedly choked AND punched and I am getting severely injured and the girl is bigger and stronger than me)just to let you know I'm kinda a small kid) so how do I defend myself or do I defend myself? Do I not do anything because its the opposite gender or not?

When someone is attacking you, gender of attacker doesn't matter.
You are allowed to defend yourself. Make sure you don't attack the attacker more than how much you are attacked but it is better to show self restraint.

And if you punish [an enemy, O believers. ], punish with an equivalent
of that with which you were harmed. But if you are patient - it is
better for those who are patient.
And be patient and your patience is not but through
Allāh. And do not grieve over them and do not be in distress over what
they conspire.Quran 16:126-127

If you are weaker than the attacker, it is better to avoid the situation or get help from others to defend yourself.
